# How to use/show multiple layers in Krita at the same time?

Tags: krita

I am used to Photoshop, moving to Krita since it is free to give it a try.
When I try to add a new "layer" in the "Layers" panel, the other layers disappear!
It is as if a layer in Krita was a new document or as if I was in "Solo" mode showing only 1 layer at a time!
however even if I export the image to JPG I only get the current layer...

After an hour of frustration I figured out that grouping the layers shows all the child layers at once (apparently top level layers behave like separate documents, that's estrange to me), but then I can't work with one layer showing the rest, it is like working blind!

Is there any way to make layers in Krita behave the way they do in Photoshop?
in other words, to be able to move/paint/redimension one layer at the same time other layers are visible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this. Right click on a layer in the layers panel, and uncheck the "Isolate Layer" option.

Comment: That worked, Thank you!
Now I understand what happened.

Comment: Coming from Photoshop I was trying to duplicate some layers and while testing different layer click combinations with control, alt or shift,
while Krita does a good job at implementing Alt+click+drag to duplicate layers just like Photoshop, it makes the layer enter "Isolate active layer" mode when you Alt+click on a layer without dragging. In Photoshop Alt+click would clip the layer with the layer below, so I ended up activating the "solo" feature inadvertedly!

Comment: Yeah . . . coming from Photoshop is often a problem. It can lull you into a false sense of security. You think you are familiar with other software because of your experience with Photoshop, however most other software tends to have its own peculiarities and shortcuts and this can lead to frustration. Sometimes it's best to try to forget Photoshop when working with other software.